# Add column in R that is dependent on multiple variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like so:

```
ID <- c('A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A' )
EXP_P <- c(62,62,62,62,62,62,62,64,64,64,67,67,67,67,67,67)
BRR <- c(61,57,66,53,54,50,55,65,71,53,51,50,58,54,55,57)
val1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3)

df <- data.frame(ID, EXP_P, BRR, val1)
```

Output:

```
   ID EXP_P BRR val1
1   A    62  61    1
2   A    62  57    1
3   A    62  66    1
4   A    62  53    1
5   A    62  54    1
6   A    62  50    1
7   A    62  55    1
8   A    64  65    2
9   A    64  71    2
10  A    64  53    2
11  A    67  51    3
12  A    67  50    3
13  A    67  58    3
14  A    67  54    3
15  A    67  55    3
16  A    67  57    3
```

I would like to add a new column `BPP` that is dependent on each of the other columns.

Rules:

1. When `val1` changes and it does not equal the row above, say from `1` to `2`, `BPP` should be same as `EXP_P`.
2. When the second occurrance of `val1` appears (by group `ID`), `BPP` should be the previous `BRR` value.
3. When the third occurrance of `val1` appears (by group `ID`), `BPP` should be the max of the last two previous `BRR` values.
4. When the fourth occurrance of `val1` appears (by group `ID`), and all subsequent occurrances of that `val1`, BPP should be the max of the last three previous `BRR` values.

Desired output:

```
   ID EXP_P BRR val1 BPP
1   A    62  61    1  62
2   A    62  57    1  61
3   A    62  66    1  61
4   A    62  53    1  66
5   A    62  54    1  66
6   A    62  50    1  66
7   A    62  55    1  54
8   A    64  65    2  64
9   A    64  71    2  65
10  A    64  53    2  71
11  A    67  51    3  67
12  A    67  50    3  51
13  A    67  58    3  51
14  A    67  54    3  58
15  A    67  55    3  58
16  A    67  57    3  58
```

Ideally I am looking for a `dplyr` solution with `mutate` but if another one is possible, this would be good also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a pretty direct solution. If you need to generalize to more lags you could use rolling max from the `RcppRoll` package, but with 3 at most this is pretty manageable to hard-code:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID, val1) %>%
  mutate(occ = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    BPP = case_when(
      occ == 1 ~ EXP_P,
      occ == 2 ~ lag(BRR),
      occ == 3 ~ pmax(lag(BRR, 1), lag(BRR, 2), na.rm = TRUE),
      TRUE ~ pmax(lag(BRR, 1), lag(BRR, 2), lag(BRR, 3), na.rm = TRUE)
    )
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 16 × 6
#    ID    EXP_P   BRR  val1   occ   BPP
#    <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#  1 A        62    61     1     1    62
#  2 A        62    57     1     2    61
#  3 A        62    66     1     3    61
#  4 A        62    53     1     4    66
#  5 A        62    54     1     5    66
#  6 A        62    50     1     6    66
#  7 A        62    55     1     7    54
#  8 A        64    65     2     1    64
#  9 A        64    71     2     2    65
# 10 A        64    53     2     3    71
# 11 A        67    51     3     1    67
# 12 A        67    50     3     2    51
# 13 A        67    58     3     3    51
# 14 A        67    54     3     4    58
# 15 A        67    55     3     5    58
# 16 A        67    57     3     6    58
```

Comment: perfect, thank you. I completely forgot about `case_when`.